# How does Haskell infer definitions for type classes?

Tags: haskell

So I am playing around with Haskell and noticed something which puzzles me. I defined a complex floating point data structure and wanted to used comparison operators on it. Initally I did this which worked fine:

```
data Cplx = Cplx Float Float deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Ord Cplx where
  (<=) a b = (<=) (normCplx a) (normCplx b)
  (>=) a b = (>=) (normCplx a) (normCplx b)
  (<) a b = (<) (normCplx a) (normCplx b)
  (>) a b = (>) (normCplx a) (normCplx b)

normCplx :: Cplx -> Float
normCplx (Cplx a1 a2) = sqrt( a1^2 + a2^2)
```

But I also noticed just declaring:

```
data Cplx = Cplx Float Float deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Ord Cplx where
  (<=) a b = (<=) (normCplx a) (normCplx b)    

normCplx :: Cplx -> Float
normCplx (Cplx a1 a2) = sqrt( a1^2 + a2^2)
```

Also got the job done just fine. How does Haskell infer the definitons for the other comparison operators given only the single definition?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally operations in the class definition may have a default implementation that call each other. So defining a handful functions in the instance resolves the recursive dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the rest is implemented just with the type-class using `(<=)` (or `compare`) - this is what "minimal implementation" in the docs here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord mean.

> Minimal complete definition: either compare or <=. Using compare can
>   be more efficient for complex types.

Sadly in this case you cannot show the source directly from Hackage but as `Ord a` implies `Eq a` it's not hard to imagine how this is done.

For example as you have `(<=)` implemented `(<)` can just be:

```
a < b = a /= b && a <= b
```

with that you get

```
a >= b = not (a < b)
```

and finaly

```
a > b = not (a <= b)
```

or something similar.

Btw as you might have seen in your first implementation you did not implement `compare`, `max` or `min` even if it's part of the type-class and this it got infered too.

Maybe you can try to guess it yourself.

### remark

David found the sources - here is the implementation right from there:

```
class  (Eq a) => Ord a  where
    compare              :: a -> a -> Ordering
    (<), (<=), (>), (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    max, min             :: a -> a -> a

    compare x y = if x == y then EQ
                  -- NB: must be '<=' not '<' to validate the
                  -- above claim about the minimal things that
                  -- can be defined for an instance of Ord:
                  else if x <= y then LT
                  else GT

    x <  y = case compare x y of { LT -> True;  _ -> False }
    x <= y = case compare x y of { GT -> False; _ -> True }
    x >  y = case compare x y of { GT -> True;  _ -> False }
    x >= y = case compare x y of { LT -> False; _ -> True }

        -- These two default methods use '<=' rather than 'compare'
        -- because the latter is often more expensive
    max x y = if x <= y then y else x
    min x y = if x <= y then x else y
    {-# MINIMAL compare | (<=) #-}
```

As you can see: if you have `compare` or `(<=)` all else follows.

Comment: For reference, the source for the default definitions (and the rest of the `Ord` class) can be found here https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/ghc-prim/GHC/Classes.hs#L128.

Comment: Is there any reason that `<=` is required instead of just `<`? Since you already have equality, you should be able to say that `<=` == `<` || `==`, I think. And in the source code above, it looks like you could just swap out `<=` for `<` in the `compare`, `max`, and `min` functions and the results would be unchanged.

Comment: Awesome! This makes a ton more sense now! Thanks alot!

Comment: @MaxGabriel of course you are right - look at the *comment* from the implementator "NB: muste be '<=' ..." - it's just to get the *claims* right ;)

Answer (score 1):

It must be said that the `Ord` typeclass is for types with [*total order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), and complex numbers do not satisfy the properties of total order.  In particular, your implementation violates the *anti-symmetry* property, that is,

```
forall a b. if a ≤ b and b ≤ a then a = b.
```

Failing to satisfy this property violates the contract of `Ord` and could result in strange bugs, depending on how the instance is used.

It might be more appropriate to apply `normCplx` where you might have relied on functionality derived from `Ord`, e.g., `` sortBy (compare `on` normCplx) `` where you might have just used `sort`.